# ToListAsync() does not complete at all

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, entity-framework-6, async-await

I want to execute some queries async.
But when I debug through the code, most times when an ToListAsync() is called the program stops.
There is no visible exception, and the callstack window is cleared.
When I press the pause button in VS, I can see the stack frame just before the current method was called.

```
var res1 = await context.Address().Where(...).ToListAsync();
var res2 = await context.Person().Where(...).ToListAsync();
var res3 = await context.Rule().Where(...).ToListAsync();
```

Sometimes the first call works, in rare cases the second too.
But at least at the third call the program stops.
I have absolutely no clue why...

Comment: What do you mean by "the program stops"? Is this, for example, a command line program?  If so then yes, it ends, because the call is non-blocking.  We need some more context here.

Comment: Are you calling `Wait` or `Result` at all further up your call stack?

Comment: It is a wpf application. The commands are within an async method. I call this from a non-async method using `var result = LoadAsync.Result()`. With _stops_ I mean it seems like the execution takes forever. The debugger will not step further.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the comments:

> It is a wpf application. The commands are within an async method. I call this from a non-async method using `var result = LoadAsync.Result();`

Right there, thats a **deadlock**. The [`DispatcherSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) tries to marshal the continuation (everything after the first `await`) back onto the dispatcher (UI) thread, which is currently blocked by the call to `LoadAsync.Result`

The solution:

1. `await` at the top of your call stack by making your method return an `async Task` instead of using `Task.Result`:

   ```
   await LoadAsync();
   ```
2. If you absolutely cant change the method at the top of of the stack to `async Task` and for some obscure reason have to still call `Task.Result`, use [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx) when awating your inner async methods. This will tell the sync context to explicitly not attempt to marshal work back to the dispatcher thread:

   ```
   var res1 = await context.Address().Where(...).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   var res2 = await context.Person().Where(...).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   var res3 = await context.Rule().Where(...).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```

Comment: It seems like in this case he should be doing (1) *and* (2). Another trick (but not-advised practice) is to at the top level do `Task.Run(() => LoadAsync()).Result` instead of `LoadAsync().Result` when the top level cannot be made `async`. This will stop the deadlocks if you have forgotten `ConfigureAwait(false)` on some of your `await`s, but typically should not be a permanent solution.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I was not aware of this until now. For anybody who need details, I found the blog post [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) from Stephen Cleary.

Comment: @TimothyShields Thanks, you saved my day...
I'm working on a broker-class that can't be made async (it's called from MS Access VBA), and the ConfigureAwait(false) didn't help.