# UnitTest to check if methods in the solution contain method-call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, methods, task

In [this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) is explained why you wouldn't want to use `async void` methods and a UnitTest to track them down and avoid them. All of this works perfect using `reflection` that scans for `async void` in all the methods.

Because we recently had a bug we want to create a similar method, which will check if there are any methods in the solution containing a [`Task#.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call. Unfortunately we can't access a method's body as a string and see if it contains `".Result;"` or something similar. As most of you probably know, `reflection` uses `metadata`. So we can get properties, methods, method's variable types, etc., but nothing substantial, like method's variable names or code inside a method itself.

I know I can access the `MSIL` as a byte-aray from the methods, and I can also convert those to hexadecimal data (for example with the code found in [this link](http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/10/07/examining-the-method-body-using-reflection-in-net-c/)). `MSIL` is used by external libraries to make compilable and runnable C# code again (even at run-time), the problem however is that you can't read the `MSIL`.

So, does anyone know a way to write a UnitTest that checks all methods in the solution and check if they call the get-property `.Result` on a Task. If any of these methods exist in the solution, the UnitTest should fail, if not it succeeds. (Preferably giving which methods contain this call, but this isn't a priority. If we know it fails we can search the method that calls it ourselves if needed.)

The reason we want to avoid `Task#.Result` is because we had a deadlock. Similar to [this SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896717/tolistasync-does-not-complete-at-all).

Comment: This sounds more like a job for static analysis than unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a unit test, you can try to write a custom rule for FxCop which checks that. It seems you can use Method.Instructions collection (FxCop object model) to find all calls to Task<>.Result.

This article shows an example implementation of similar check: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30666/Steps-to-Write-Your-Own-Custom-Rule-using-FXCOP