# Async / await on windows form application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to learn and implement async / await keywords on my application. I'm using an API to get data then showing them on my forms. When I try to call methods from an console application there is no problem. But if I call my async methods from Form_Shown event also there no exception but methods not working.

So I'm calling my RefreshOrLoadDataToCache() method on Form_Shown event.

```
private async void LogTimeReport_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some syncronous operations

    RefreshOrLoadDataToCache(); // Async methods in it 

    // Some syncronous operations
}
```

In my this method created a task and wait for it.

```
private async void RefreshOrLoadDataToCache()
{
    if (IsNeededToCallAPI())
    {
        var taskForTimeEntries = LoadTimeEntriesTemp();
        Task.WhenAll(taskForTimeEntries);

        DataTable dtTimeEntriesTemp = taskForTimeEntries.Result;
        DataTable dtEventsTemp = LoadEventsTemp();

        dtTimeEntriesTemp.Merge(dtEventsTemp);
    }
    else
        BindGridViews();
}
```

This my async method.

```
 private async Task<DataTable> LoadTimeEntriesTemp()
 { 
     TimeEntryHandler timeHandler = new TimeEntryHandler();

     TimeEntryResponse response = await timeHandler.GetTimeEntries();

     DataTable dt = DatatableHelper.ToDataTable<TimeEntry>(response.TimeEntries);

     foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
     {
        // Some operations on DataTable
     }
     return dt;
 }
```

In this method I'm connecting to API and getting results. I think my problem is about this method. Because when I call this method from console application it returns data. But from form application it waits for a long time but there is no result or exception.

```
private async Task<TimeEntryResponse> GetTimeEntries()
{
    using (var client = new AuthorizedHttpClient(_client))
    {
        var data = await client.GetAsync<TimeEntryResponse>(parameters);

        if (data.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var response = (TimeEntryResponse)data.ContentObj;
            response.Pages = int.Parse(data.Headers.GetValues("X-Pages").First());
            response.Page = int.Parse(data.Headers.GetValues("X-Page").First());
            response.TotalRecords = int.Parse(data.Headers.GetValues("X-Records").First());
            return response;
        }
        return new TimeEntryResponse() { TimeEntries = null, STATUS = "ERROR" };
    }
}
```

I thought that there is something I'm missing about asyncronous calls on windows forms. How can I fix my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem here:

```
var taskForTimeEntries = LoadTimeEntriesTemp();
Task.WhenAll(taskForTimeEntries);

DataTable dtTimeEntriesTemp = taskForTimeEntries.Result;
```

At first, why do you use `Task.WhenAll` when you have just one task? That way you leak the task returned by `Task.WhenAll` which will be completed and indicate that all your tasks that are passed to `Task.WhenAll` are completed. It will wait for the task synchronously which will cause deadlock.

There is a rule for async/await which states **await in all ways**
So right approach is:

```
DataTable dtTimeEntriesTemp = await LoadTimeEntriesTemp();
```

Also, you should await on `RefreshOrLoadDataToCache();` in your event handler if you want to do synchronous operations related to its result.

Here is a great article by Stephen Cleary [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) which describes your problem in more details.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of problems with your code

1. You mark a method as `async`, but you don't await on the operation inside. You currently do this because `RefreshOrLoad` is `async void`. It actually needs to be `async Task`, where the underlying returned task is the ongoing async operation. Then, the returned `Task` should be awaited on:

   ```
   private async void LogTimeReport_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Some syncronous operations

       await RefreshOrLoadDataToCache(); // Async methods in it 

       // Some syncronous operations
   }
   ```
2. `RefreshOrLoad` is an async method. You use `Task.WhenAll`, which is used for asynchronously waiting on multiple tasks, but you don't `await` on it either. Then, you call `.Result`, [which causes your code to effectively **deadlock**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896717/tolistasync-does-not-complete-at-all/25899982#25899982). All that's needed is to await the task returning from `LoadTimeEntriesTemp`:

   ```
   private async Task RefreshOrLoadDataToCache()
   {
       if (IsNeededToCallAPI())
       {
           DataTable dtTimeEntriesTemp = await LoadTimeEntriesTemp();
           DataTable dtEventsTemp = LoadEventsTemp();

           dtTimeEntriesTemp.Merge(dtEventsTemp);
       }
       else
           BindGridViews();
   }
   ```

   I'd also note that you should use the `*Async` postfix with your async methods.

When fixing these, you'll see that your code behaves as expected, being asynchronous all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Method `RefreshOrLoadDataToCache()` is marked as async yet it does not use await on `Task.WhenAll()` and `LogTimeReport_Shown()` does not have to be async. :

```
private async void RefreshOrLoadDataToCache()
{
  if (IsNeededToCallAPI())
  {
    var taskForTimeEntries = LoadTimeEntriesTemp();

    DataTable dtTimeEntriesTemp = await taskForTimeEntries; // call await here
    DataTable dtEventsTemp = LoadEventsTemp();

    dtTimeEntriesTemp.Merge(dtEventsTemp);
  }
  else
    BindGridViews();
 }
```