# c# async - await ToListAsync returns undefined

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

```
public async Task<JsonResult> getEmployee(int roleId)
{
    var emp = await db.tbl_employee.Where(e => e.roleId == roleId).ToListAsync();
    return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This action returns undefined but if I remove the await like this

```
public async Task<JsonResult> getEmployee(int roleId)
{
    var emp = db.tbl_employee.Where(e => e.roleId == roleId).ToListAsync();
    return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

it will return the result that I wanted. I also tried tried this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25899982/9367841

```
public async Task<JsonResult> getEmployee(int roleId)
{
    var emp = await db.tbl_employee.Where(e => e.roleId == roleId).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `.ConfigureAwait(false)` and why do you need that?

Comment: No, I only tried it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25899982/9367841), I thought it will fix my problem but it also return undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it.

if you are using this action

```
public async Task<JsonResult> getEmployee(int roleId)
{
    var emp = db.tbl_employee.Where(e => e.roleId == roleId).ToListAsync();
    return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

//I'm using angularjs to get the data from server

```
$http.post("../controller/getEmployee", { roleId: id }).then(function (r) {
      console.log(r.data);
})
```

the result would be like this (from console.log(r.data))

```
{Result: Array(1), Id: 50, Exception: null, Status: 5, IsCanceled: false, …}
AsyncState: null
CreationOptions: 0
Exception: null
Id: 50
IsCanceled: false
IsCompleted: true
IsFaulted: false
Result: [{…}]
Status: 5
__proto__: Object
```

to get the list of employee. instead of using r.data, use r.data["Result"] instead.

```
$http.post("../controller/getEmployee", { roleId: id }).then(function (r) {
      $scope.list = r.data["Result"];
})
```

But if you are using this action

```
public async Task<JsonResult> getEmployee(int roleId)
{
    var emp = await db.tbl_employee.Where(e => e.roleId == roleId).ToListAsync();
    return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You can get the list of employee using r.data.

```
$http.post("../controller/getEmployee", { roleId: id }).then(function (r) {
      $scope.list = r.data;
})
```

**Sorry I didn't show how I get the data, the problem was there, not on the server-side.**

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen this before. Can you try the following please?

```
public JsonResult getEmployee(int roleId)
{
    var emp = await db.tbl_employee.Where(e => e.roleId == roleId).ToListAsync();
    return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

`ToListAsync` returns a `Task<>`

**edit** see here: [Is it correct if i am using await + ToListAsync() over IQueryable which is not define as a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759967/is-it-correct-if-i-am-using-await-tolistasync-over-iqueryable-which-is-not-d)

Comment: got this error "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<JsonResult>'." @scgough